# Application Event not firing in lightning

Tags: lightning, error, event

I am having problems firing an application Event, i do not know what i am messing.
Here is my code:
**APP:**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:QuizWelcomeComponent />
    <c:QuizQuestionComponent /> 
</aura:application>
```

**QuizWelcomeComponent:** (should fire an event to QuizQuestionComponent component)

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:registerEvent name="StartQuiz" type="c:StartQuizEvent"/>
        ......
        ......
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.StartQuiz}">Commencer le Quiz</button>
</aura:component>
```

controller:

```
StartQuiz : function(component, event, helper) {
        var StartEvent =  $A.get("e.c:StartQuiz");
        console.log('StartEvent = '+StartEvent);
        StartEvent.fire();

}
```

StartQuizEvent:

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">

</aura:event>
```

**ERROR:** console.log('StartEvent = '+StartEvent) from the QuizWelcomeComponent component returns **undefined** so I do not know what I am doing wrong, I even copied the firing code from the APPLICATION EVENT DOCs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define the name of the application event in javascript controller same as the application event name.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:registerEvent name="StartQuiz" type="c:StartQuizEvent"/>
<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.StartQuiz}">Commencer le Quiz</button>
```

Controller-

```
({
StartQuiz : function(component, event, helper) {
    var StartEvent =  $A.get("e.c:StartQuizEvent");
    console.log('StartEvent = '+StartEvent);
    StartEvent.fire();
}})
```

Comment: No i dont think so, The name of the registerEvent does not have to be the same as the name of the event itself, you can refer to this article https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_example.htm. this is just an example .

Comment: @MerabtiIbrahim In the application event it is necessary to take name of the application event in javaccript controller like $A.get("e.c:StartQuizEvent"); I have updated the Answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right regarding the name of the event in the controller, it seems so obvious. thank you

Comment: Glad to resolve the issue.

Comment: After a long struggle, It worked.... thank you...